# Apply module_defaults attribute to a role

Tags: ansible

I have the following file structure:

```
webserver.yml
emailserver.yml
roles/
    common/
        tasks/
            main.yml
```

`emailserver.yml` and `webserver.yml` look like:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - common
```

And `main.yml`:

```
- name: apt-get update
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    force_apt_get: yes

- name: apt-get upgrade
  apt:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
    force_apt_get: yes
```

In order to avoid repeating `force_apt_get: yes`, I would like to use [the `module_defaults` attribute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html) for this role:

```
module_defaults:
  apt:
    force_apt_get: yes
```

I've tried to include that at the top of `main.yml` but I'm getting a syntax error.

**How can I apply a `module_defaults` attribute to a role's tasks?**

(an alternative is to add `module_defaults` to both `webserver.yml` and `emailserver.yml`, but it means code duplication and having the common role configuration spread over a number of files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a block in the role task file, `main.yml`:

```
- block:
  - name: apt-get update
    apt:
      update_cache: yes

  - name: apt-get upgrade
    apt:
      name: "*"
      state: latest

  become: yes
  module_defaults:
    apt:
      force_apt_get: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I apply a `module_defaults` attribute to a role?

It is not possible as of current Ansible version (2.7). `module_defaults` is a `Play` attribute only.

Comment: Thanks - I've reworded the question: "*How can I apply a `module_defaults` attribute **to a role?***" ==> "*How can I apply a `module_defaults` attribute **to a role's tasks?***".